# How can I eliminate the subtotals for the rows but leave the grand total on a sencha pivot table?

Tags: extjs

I am trying to eliminate the subtotals for the rows and just leave the grand total at the far right and the bottom. Is there a way to omit the subtotal column after each final drill down on the top axis?[report output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3f3i.png)

I have tried implementing the configs on the top axis of "rowSubTotalPosition:none" and I don't get any response.

```
matrix: {
    type: 'local',
    store: store1,

    aggregate: [{
        dataIndex: 'total',
        header: 'Total',
        renderer: 'bonusTotal',
        rowSubTotalsPosition: 'last',
        exportStyle: {
            format: 'Currency',
            alignment: {
                horizontal: 'Right'
            }
        }
    }],

    leftAxis: [{
        header: 'Health Coach',
        width: 200,
        viewLayoutType: 'compact',
        rowSubTotalsPosition: 'none',
        compactViewColumnWidth: 100,
        dataIndex: 'full',
        id: name + 'user_id',
        reference: 'user_id',
        exportStyle: {
            alignment: {
                horizontal: 'Right'
            }
        }
    }, ],
    topAxis: [{
        dataIndex: 'year',
        header: 'Year',
        width: 100,
        labelRenderer: 'yearLabelRenderer',
        id: 'year',
        exportStyle: {
            alignment: {
                horizontal: 'Right'
            }
        }

    }, {
        dataIndex: 'month',
        header: 'Month',
        width: 100,
        labelRenderer: 'monthLabelRenderer',
        exportStyle: {
            alignment: {
                horizontal: 'Right'
            }
        }

    }],
}
```

The table doesn't change at all and the row subtotal continues to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your picture, what you realy want is to remove the **Column** subtotal, so instead of using `rowSubTotalsPosition: 'none'` you should use `colSubTotalPosition:'none'`

```
{
     xtype:  'pivotgrid',
     matrix: {
         type: 'local',
         store: store1, 
         colSubTotalPosition: 'none',
         aggregate: [{
             dataIndex: 'value',
             header: 'Total',
             aggregator: 'sum',
             width: 120
         }]
         //rest of your matrix configs
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I implemented that and it is still outputting the same information in the same manner, I'm not sure why. I'm using sencha classic. Is there something I could be missing?

Comment: Which version of Extjs are you using?

Comment: Also, can you post an image showing the result  (don't need to show any confidential data)?

Comment: I'm using Extjs version 6.7

Comment: I added a link in the question above for the result output. The bold "total" is what I would like to get rid of.

Comment: Updated the answer, check if this is what you really want

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.